# How to align pause icon to the center of the video in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I align the play/Pause icon to the center of the video? I have tried Center and Align Widget but its always off by few pixels not exactly centered.

```
  Widget _buildPlayerController() {  
    return SizedBox(  
      height: _screenWidth / _controller.value.aspectRatio,  
      width: _screenWidth,  
      child: Stack(  
        children: <Widget>[  
          Center(              
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 60,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                _controller.value.isPlaying
                    ? await _controller.pause()
                    : await _controller.play();
                if (_controller.value.isPlaying) _showController = false;
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where this Center widget is being placed?

Comment: I have added the full widget @PedroMassango

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of IconButton, try to use InkWell

```
      Center(
        child: InkWell(
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 60,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) _showController = false;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I am super late to answer that question. But this will help

```
Positioned.fill(
  child: Center(
    child: InkWell(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.play_circle_outline_rounded,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 80,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

**MY Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks...perfect answer.